# Why is the date dialog asking to click thrice to dismiss

Tags: android, datepicker

```
public class QuickIWantActivity extends Activity implements
        OnDateSetListener {
.....
.....
.....

dateET.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog datePickDiag = new DatePickerDialog(
        QuickIWantActivity.this, QuickIWantActivity.this, cal
            .get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        datePickDiag.show();
        return true;
        }
    });

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {

    int month = monthOfYear + 1;
    dateET.setText(dayOfMonth + "- " + month + "- " + year);
}

}
```

So on touching dateET which is an EditText it opens the datepicker, i set the new date and click set, it won't get dismissed, i click set again, even now it wont get dismissed, finally it gets dismissed when i click set for the 3rd time

Comment: You might consider explaining better precisely what your symptoms are.

Comment: yeah, added the description.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't starting more than one dialog as you touch the `EditText`? You can easily test this by caching the `datePickDialog` and creating a new one in the `onTouch` only if another instance isn't currently visible.

Comment: should i use **view.dismiss()** in the last line of **onDateSet**??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onTouch` receives three events (normal sequence):

```
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
```

and since you are not checking any of them (and returning true), your code is executed 3 times (one for each event).

Solution:

Use `onClick()` (this is what I would do) or add the check:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

switch (event.getAction()) { 
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog datePickDiag = new DatePickerDialog(
        QuickIWantActivity.this, QuickIWantActivity.this, cal
            .get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        datePickDiag.show();
        return false;
        }
    });
break;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain on: **MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN** is for? i mean how is it different from the other 2?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: `ACTION_DOWN` is a finger initially touching the screen. `ACTION_MOVE` is an already-down finger sliding on the screen. `ACTION_UP` is a finger leaving the screen.

Comment: OnTouch() receives ACTION_DOWN event when your finger touches the view, ACTION_MOVE when you move your finger around (while still touching the screen) and ACTION_UP when you lift your finger. Returning True informs the system that you will handle the 3 events, returning false informs the system that Android will handle the rest of the event (You receive ACTION_DOWN only and the system handles the other 2). You can only use return false, but I recommend adding the check to be extra sure or even better use onClick instead